# How to Restrict one body to force another body in Box2d?

Tags: iphone, box2d-iphone

im creating simple breakout game, in which i have continuing falling bricks which are to be disappeared when ball hits it. but when ball hits that brick, it applies force to it and bricks go upward. so i want ball to stop forcing brick!? , is there anyway in Box2d to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use kinematic bodies for bricks

```
body->SetType( b2_kinematicBody );
```

Comment: yes i had already tried that, but it is not working properly, bricks changes their behavior other than force, it seems light weight. as far i know kinematicBody similar to dynamicBody but no accepting forces. but are there any other deference in their behavior?

Comment: b2_kinematicBody - 
A kinematic body moves under simulation according to its velocity. Kinematic bodies do not respond to forces. They can be moved manually by the user, but normally a kinematic body is moved by setting its velocity. A kinematic body behaves as if it has infinite mass, however, Box2D stores zero for the mass and the inverse mass. Kinematic bodies do not collide with other static or kinematic bodies.(Box2D doc)